# How to make gmail remember my Add-on open state?

Tags: gmail-addons

I am working on Gmail Add-on using Google Apps Script, it is already published to Gsuite marketplace.

I can see that Gmail is remembering the last open state of google provided add-ons like Calendar, Keep etc, and keep it open even if I refresh / reopen the browser.

But, this is not happening for my add-on.

How can I make Gmail remember my add-on as last opened and open it by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to store strings as key-value pairs in apps script.